# Weird behaviour maven tests

Tags: java, maven

I tought I was quite familiar with maven and it's behaviour but i'm not figuring out this one.
I have a parent project in which i defined the property:

```
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

which I know is meant to not build test jars.

I then created three properties still in the parent project like the following

```
<skipChild1Test>true</skipChild1Test>
<skipChild2Test>true</skipChild2Test>
<skipChild3Test>true</skipChild3Test>
```

Each of the child projects have a maven-surefire-plugin section like the following

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipChildNtest}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Basically i want to statically declare in the parent POM which child projects should run the test and which not.

However those properties seems to have no effect at all and all it's driven by the original property

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
```

which runs the tests on the children if false and it does not if it is true.

I always issue the command `mvn test` on the parent project

Did I configured the children wrong?

**UPDATE**

Looking on the maven-surefire-plugin test goal details i read the following about the skip parameter:

*"*Set this to "true" to bypass unit tests entirely. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, especially if you enable it using the "maven.test.skip" property, because maven.test.skip disables both running the tests and compiling the tests. Consider using the skipTests parameter instead.*"*

So what I read on stackoverflow and many other places was not correct.
maven.test.skip drives both packagin and running the tests

Comment: Please, take the solution out of your question and put it in an answer, then after some time you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just overwrite the property in the child projects with `<maven.test.skip>${skipChildNtest}</maven.test.skip>`

So then the property `<maven.test.skip>` in your parent project would not interfere with your child projects.

Maybe you can also get rid of the plugin declaration in your child projects, but of that im not sure.

Comment: Hi Reto, you are right but shouldn't the property maven.test.skip simply drive test jars generation? I tought the skipTests was the one to drive running tests or not

Comment: I update my question with something i found on the maven surefire plugin documentation

Comment: No I think it is used to execute tests or not in context of a maven goal. So if you do a "mvn install", and property "<maven.test.skip>" is set to true, the maven build will not execute the tests during "mvn install". If it is set to false, it will execute the tests, and if one fails, the maven build is aborted. The same is true for other maven goals like "mvn package" etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Did I configured the children wrong?

There are several related properties for the Surefire plugin: [`skipTests`](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/573d44926a28ce13345da19ed813510f1725f159/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L201), [`skipExec`](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/573d44926a28ce13345da19ed813510f1725f159/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L220) and [`skip`](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/573d44926a28ce13345da19ed813510f1725f159/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L228).

When you set the `skipTests` property in the configuration, it [overrides the older `skip` property](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/573d44926a28ce13345da19ed813510f1725f159/maven-surefire-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefirePlugin.java#L511) that you're setting through the `maven.test.skip` property.

The corresponding properties and config names are:

| Property | Config |
| --- | --- |
| `skipTests` | `skipTests` |
| `maven.test.skip.exec` | `skipExec` |
| `maven.test.skip` | `skip` |

To correspond to the `maven.test.skip` property, you should use:

```
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skipChildNtest}</skip>
    </configuration>
```

instead.

You could also consider the plugin's advice, and use `skipTests` for both, to still compile the tests but not run the,.

Comment: on the official documentation it says about skipExec
"Deprecated. Use skipTests instead."

Comment: @badvi93d thanks; keeping track of how those three properties interact is tricky enough, without deprecation in the mix. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

As suggested by Reto I simply redeclared maven.test.skip in all child projects. The value is still configured in the parent project. As an example:

From a parent perspective, i define the following property:

```
<skipChild1Test>true</skipChild1Test>
```

From CHILD1 perspective i define the following property:

```
<maven.test.skip>${skipChild1Test}</maven.test.skip>
```

Comment: So basically that was my answer as well